# Poor scrolling performance for UITableView containing cell with a UITextView whose scrollEnabled = NO

Tags: uitableview, scroll, uitextview

I have a table view whose cells contain a UITextView. I want to disable the text view's scrolling but when I set it (scrollEnabled = NO) the table's scrolling behavior is just horrible - rather than smooth scrolling it is jumpy and jerky. I would have thought that turning scrolling off in the table view cell's UITextview would have improved overall table scrolling performance if anything.

Does anyone know what I might be overlooking here?

Comment: I confirm that UITextView lowers the quality of the scroll inside a UITableView. Took me 3 days to find why my scrolling performance was so low. Too bad Apple.

Answer (score 4):

OK - for anyone interested. I found that setting the content size of the uitextview to be the same as its text size fixed the problem (though I am still mystified as to why setting scrollEnabled to NO should have such strange effects - like it was dropping frames from an animation). Anyway what this does is effectively tell the view that it doesn't have to scroll because everything is visible.

Thanks to anyone who noodled this query.

Comment: I can confirm that setting scrollEnabled to NO on the text view adversely affects performance when it is contained in a scrollView.

Comment: @QBit can you post an example code for the fix you have found?

Answer (score 0):

It sound very strange that this will hurt the table view's scrolling performance. Where do u call `scrollEnable=NO` ? Check again if this is the only change u done..

Anyway if u don't want any user interaction try using `textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO`